# Can we use Global parameters for Creating an ADLS/DataBricks linked service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I started working on azure data factory and while trying to create Linked service for ADLS, there were some fields for connection parameters as shown below.
[image: parameters for an adls linked service]

And I have provided the parameter values as global parameters in the ADF
[image]

I tried by providing the global parameter name in the provided columns of ADLS linked service, but not able to fetch the data. and getting error as below.
[image]

How can I fetch the parameter values from global parameters for an ADLS linked service creation?
Is there any way to do it? Or do we need to manually enter the details while creating linked service?

I have found a solution for SQL linked service, where the variables are stored in a database and use it while creating an SQL linked service. Is Any method like this is available for ADLS linked service creation.

Any leads appreciated!

Comment: The usage is wrong, global parameter can not directly been used in linked service. The right way is: `Global Parameters -> Pipeline -> DataSet -> Linked Service` .

Comment: I have post an answer, you can have a look.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the expression in your screenshot is not right.

Second, global parameters should been used based on pipeline. The expression always been: `@pipeline().globalParameters.<parameterName>`

The right way is below steps:(I use cosmosdb as an example.)

1, create your linked service, create the required parameters, but don't give the value.

2, create the dataset, and create the required parameter.

3, pass the value:  Global Parameters -> Pipeline -> DataSet -> Linked Service.

[image]

[image]

[image]

By the way, till 2020/10/19, only the following services provide a convenient UI to pass in parameters. For other services you need to write manually.

[image]

For example,

```
{
    "name": "YourLinkedServiceName",
    "properties": {
        "type": "yourservicetype",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": xxxxxx"
        },
        "connectVia": null,
        "parameters": {
            "parametername": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to pass in parameters as attributes of the linked service.

Comment: ```By the way, till 2020/10/19, only the following services provide a convenient UI to pass in parameters. For other services you need to write manually.```
So for Databricks and ADLS linked services passing parameter from global variable is not possible?

Comment: @Antony Take a look of the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services#supported-data-stores `For other types, you can parameterize the linked service by editing the JSON on UI.`I have written the method of using global variables in the answer. You can have a try on your side.